# how can I know that drag out session ended outside the application

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

how to know that drag out session ended outside the application.

for example I have one application which contain 3 images and if I drag out one image then how shall i know that drag out session ended out side the application not inside the application .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found one way i.e - 
(void)draggingSession:(NSDraggingSession *)session endedAtPoint:(NSPoint)screenPoint operation:(NSDragOperation)operation

using this method I got the dragging end point in screen coordinate  and using [window frame] I got the the screen point of my window . and by comparing two screen points it is easy to find out whether drag out ended within application or outside application window .

Answer (score 0):

Check the `mouseLocation` of your drag `NSEvent` against your view to see where the drag ended.